# Block booting into safe mode

Tags: stock-android, safe-mode, builds

I am using a porn blocker to protect my kids. But I got to know that there is a workaround to that by rebooting into safe mode. I also tested it and I was able to access everything.

Now my paid subscription to blocker seems useless. I am also worried about the kids.

So is there any way I can block safe mode in my device?

Like editing `build.prop` file or making any other change and safe mode blocker.

Comment: You can set a password for the primary account and set-up a secondary account for your kids. AFAIR after a reboot the password is required by Android so every time they reboot the device they need to come to you. I am not 100% sure but I would assume that this also applies to safe mode.

Comment: No, this method cannot solve my problem. As sometimes I have to give the smartphone to them for longer times. I am looking for a way to totally disable this functionality.

Comment: Do you have root access? You can write a Magisk module that sets persist.sys.safemode property to 0 before Android framework is loaded. Otherwise, you can't disable safe mode. Android doesn't offer a way out. Also, build.prop files cannot be changed without root access, so you should mention whether you have root access or not if you are thinking about solutions which depend upon root.

Comment: @ I don't have root access. Can you offer any other solution?

Comment: Another solution is to disable Play Store, package installer app, and stock browser apps that came with the phone. Even if your kid manages to boot into safe mode, they need access to a market app to install apps, or package installer to sideload apps, or stock browser to download apk files. As such, the two ways an app can still be installed in a fully patched device is via adb. There is no solution for app installation through  adb though.

Comment: @Firelord...Seems like a good option. But how can we disable all these apps without root access?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a kiosk app though? You can setup a kiosk app so that your kid only see and access the set of apps you want them to see and access. Even if your kid manages to install an app from safe mode, what good would it do to them since they can't run that app in safe mode, and when booted into normal mode you are gonna give them kiosk environment only.

Comment: You can search our website about disabling apps without root access. We have many such questions. Do know that some devices such as from Xiaomi don't like any system apps being disabled, and so, you might end up unable to boot the device afterwards. Proceed only if you are running a device close to Vanilla Android, such as from Google, OnePlus, Motorola, Nokia, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When supervised with Google's own Family Link, safe mode option becomes disabled.